# Miller-Rabin Large Prime Generator in Rust

Tags: performance, c, haskell, reinventing-the-wheel, rust

I implemented the Miller-Rabin prime test in Rust and made a program to generate large primes.

I have also implemented the same program in C and Haskell and the Rust version is the slowest. I am looking for advice on how to improve performance and how to improve my Rust style code.

The code for the program in Rust, Haskell, and C are below is compiled using `cargo build --release`. The contents of the Rust toml file follow the rust code.

For an input initial number `n=10^500` and number of tests `k=40`, the time taken is 4.5 seconds on my computer (1 sec for C, 2 sec for Haskell) and the answer I get for the next prime is `10^500+961`. Each program is run with `n` and `k` as the arguments, e.g. `cargo run <n> <k>`.

**Rust code, main.rs**, compiled with `cargo build --release`

```
use num;
use rand;
use num_bigint::{BigUint, RandBigInt};
use num::FromPrimitive;
use num::{Zero, One};
use std::env;

const TRIAL_DIVISORS : [u32; 167] = [3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,
  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,
 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397,
 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467,
 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569,
 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823,
 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911,
 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997];

fn main() {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let n = args[1].parse::<BigUint>().expect("Error reading bignum.");
    let ntests = args[2].parse::<usize>().expect("Error reading ntests.");

    let p = find_prime(n, ntests);

    println!("{}", p);


}

fn find_prime(mut n : BigUint, ntests : usize) -> BigUint {
    // If the input is even, it should be made odd.
    if &n % 2u32 == BigUint::zero() {
        n += 1u32;
    }

    let two : BigUint = BigUint::from_u32(2).unwrap();

    while !mr_isprime(&n, &ntests) {
        n += &two;
    }

    n
}

fn mr_isprime(n : &BigUint, ntests : &usize) -> bool {


    for i in TRIAL_DIVISORS.iter() {
        if n % i  == BigUint::zero() {
            if n==&(BigUint::from_u32(*i).unwrap()) {
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
    }

    let (d,r) = decompose(n);
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let two : BigUint = BigUint::from_u32(2).unwrap();

    for _ in 0..*ntests {
        let a: BigUint = rng.gen_biguint_range(&two,&(n-2u16));
        if trial_composite(n, &d, &r, &a) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}


fn trial_composite(n: &BigUint, d: &BigUint,
            r: &usize, a: &BigUint) -> bool {
    let mut x = a.modpow(&d, &n);
    if (x==BigUint::one()) || (x==(n-1u32)) {
        return false;
    }
    let two = BigUint::from_u32(2).unwrap();
    for i in 0..(r-1) {
        let e = d*( &two << i);
        x = a.modpow(&e,n);
        if n - 1u32 == x {
            return false;
        }
    }

    true
}

fn decompose(n : &BigUint) -> (BigUint, usize) {
    // Split number such that
    // n = d*2^r + 1
    let mut d = n - 1u32;
    let mut r : usize = 0;
    while (&d % 2u32).is_zero() {
        r += 1;
        d /= 2u32;
    }
    (d, r)

}
```

**Cargo.toml**

```
[package]
name = "miller_rabin"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = [""]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
num = "0.2.0"
num-bigint = { version = "0.2.2", features = ["rand"] }
rand = "0.6.5"
```

**Haskell code, miller_rabin.hs**. Compiled with `ghc -threaded -O2 miller_rabin.hs -o miller_rabin`

```
module Main where

import System.Random (StdGen, getStdGen, randomRs)
import System.Environment (getArgs)


trial_divisors = [ 3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,
  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,
 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397,
 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467,
 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569,
 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823,
 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911,
 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997]

main :: IO ()
main = do
    g <- getStdGen
    args <- getArgs 
    let number = read . head $ args :: Integer
        ntests = read $ args !! 1 :: Int
        p = find_prime g ntests number
    putStrLn . show $ p



miller_rabin :: StdGen -> Int -> Integer -> Bool
miller_rabin g k n = if any (\d -> n `mod` d == 0) trial_divisors
                        then if any (\d -> n == d) trial_divisors 
                            then True
                            else False
                        else all (not . trial_composite n d r) $
                             take k (randomRs (2, n-2) g)    
    where 
        (d, r) = decompose (n-1) 0


trial_composite :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Bool
trial_composite n d r a = let x = fastPow a d n in
    if (x == 1) || (x==n-1) 
    then False
    else all ((/=) (n-1)) $ map (\i -> fastPow a (d*(2^i)) n) [0..r-1]

decompose :: Integer -> Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
decompose d r 
    | d `mod` 2 == 0 = decompose (d `div` 2) (r+1)
    | otherwise = (d, r) 


fastPow :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
fastPow base 1 m = mod base m
fastPow base pow m | even pow = mod ((fastPow base (div pow 2) m) ^ 2) m
                   | odd  pow = mod ((fastPow base (div (pow-1) 2) m) ^ 2 * base) m




find_prime :: StdGen -> Int -> Integer -> Integer
find_prime g k n 
    | even n    = find_prime_odd g k (n+1)
    | otherwise = find_prime_odd g k n
  where
    find_prime_odd g k n = case miller_rabin g k n of
                            True  -> n
                            False -> find_prime g k (n+2)
```

**C code, miller_rabin.c**, compiled with `gcc -O2 miller_rabin_find_prime.c -o miller_rabin -lgmp`

```
#include <gmp.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NDIVISORS 167

const int trial_divisors[NDIVISORS] = {3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,
  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,
 241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
 317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397,
 401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467,
 479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569,
 571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
 647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
 739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823,
 827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911,
 919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997};


bool trial_composite(mpz_t n, mpz_t d, unsigned long int r, 
                    mpz_t a, mpz_t x, mpz_t tmp) {
  mpz_powm(x, a, d, n);
  mpz_sub_ui(tmp,n,1);
  if ((mpz_cmp_ui(x,1)==0) || (mpz_cmp(x,tmp)==0)) {
    return false;
  }
  for (unsigned long int i=0; i<r; i++) {
    mpz_mul_2exp(tmp, d, i);
    mpz_powm(x, a, tmp, n);
    mpz_sub_ui(tmp, n, 1);
    if (mpz_cmp(x,tmp)==0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

bool mr_test(mpz_t n, int numtests) {


  mpz_t d;
  unsigned long int r=0;
  mpz_init(d);
  mpz_t tmp;
  mpz_init(tmp);
  mpz_sub_ui(d,n,1);

  // Decompose into d*2^r + 1 = n
  while (mpz_divisible_ui_p(d,2)) {
    mpz_fdiv_q_2exp(d,d,1);
    r++;
  }


  // Trial division
  for (int i=0; i<NDIVISORS; i++) {
    if (mpz_divisible_ui_p(n,trial_divisors[i])) {
      if (mpz_cmp_ui(n, trial_divisors[i])==0) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }




  gmp_randstate_t rstate;
  gmp_randinit_default(rstate);

  mpz_t x;

  mpz_init(x);
  mpz_t a;
  mpz_init(a);

  for (int k=0; k<numtests; k++) {
    mpz_sub_ui(tmp, n, 4);
    mpz_urandomm(a, rstate, tmp);
    mpz_add_ui(a,a,2);
    if (trial_composite(n,d,r,a,x,tmp)) {
      return false;
    }

  }

  mpz_clear(d);
  mpz_clear(a);
  mpz_clear(x);
  mpz_clear(tmp);

  return true;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  srand(time(NULL));


  mpz_t n;
  int flag;
  mpz_init(n);
  mpz_set_ui(n,0);
  flag = mpz_set_str(n, argv[1], 10);
  assert(flag==0);

  int k = atoi(argv[2]);

  if (mpz_divisible_ui_p(n,2)) {
    mpz_add_ui(n,n,1);
  }

  bool p;
  while (!mr_test(n,k)) {
    mpz_add_ui(n,n,2);
  }

  mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);
  printf("\n");

  mpz_clear(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can add the C and Haskell code, I can do that in a few hours (wanted to focus on the rust code for this question)

Comment: Note that the other languages *can* imply [tag:comparative-review]. Make sure to mark the variant you want to get reviewed.

Comment: @Stargateur Haskell's `Integer` is an arbitrary large integer, there's no external library required (although GHC usually uses GMP in its implementation).

Comment: @Stargateur, I used GMP bigint in C and Haskell’s builtin Integer type which has arbitrary size

Comment: @Stargateur, I just added the code for the `C` and `Haskell` versions of the program.

Comment: it's hard to follow without explanation of your code, I don't know how this is suppose to work, but I see some things that could be a problem, you often build a `BigUint` that you already build before. Also each time your function is call you generate a new rng.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. Since adding comments has explicitly been suggested in the answers, adding comments partly invalidates the answer and potentially creates a mess. We take that quite seriously here. Feel free to post a follow-up question in time, instead.

Comment: @Mast, Oops! Should I revert the changes?

Comment: I've already done that, don't worry :-)

Answer (score 4):

> I am looking for advice on how to improve performance and how to improve my Rust style code.

Not so applicable, but some minor C comments

**Over specifying array size**

`trial_divisors[]` array size is specified with a constant and initialized with *maybe* the correct number of initializers.  Avoid that *maybe*.

Instead initialize, then form the size.

```c
const int trial_divisors[] = {
  3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,
  43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
  // ...
  919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997
};

#define NDIVISORS (sizeof trial_divisors / sizeof trial_divisors[0])
```

**Add comments**

The goal, algorithm, use restrictions, etc of the functions are not obvious - some more light commentary is warranted.

**Vertical white-spaces**

Blank lines in functions appeared excessive.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I was not aware of that method of finding the size of an array.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a Rust user, so I can't say much about style, but I can see an optimisation in `trial_composite`:

> ```
>         x = a.modpow(&e,n);
> ```

You already have \$x^{e/2}\$, so all you need to do is square it. I.e. this line should be (suitably corrected to compile)

```
        x = x.modpow(2u32,n);
```

or

```
        x = x * x % n;
```

There may also be a further, minor, optimisation in pulling out a local constant for `n - 1u32` so as to avoid having to do the subtraction each time round the loop.

---

There is one point of style which I think is pretty universal:

> ```
>             if n==&(BigUint::from_u32(*i).unwrap()) {
>                 return true
>             }
>             return false
> ```

is an overly complicated way of writing

```
            return n==&(BigUint::from_u32(*i).unwrap())
```

Comment: So changing the way of calculating the exponential to  `x = x * x % n;` had a significant improvement on the performance. From 4.5 seconds to 1.5 seconds. Can't remember why I used this method, but I first used it in the C version (C GMP has a specific function for a*d^e).